# How can I check existence of texture in shader programming?

Tags: shader, hlsl, directx-9

`g_MeshTexture` : texture file name

```
sampler MeshTextureSampler = 
sampler_state
{
    Texture = <g_MeshTexture>;
    MipFilter = LINEAR;
    MinFilter = LINEAR;
    MagFilter = LINEAR;
};
```

: sampler

I use "`tex2D(MeshTextureSampler, In.TextureUV)`"

Which condition in HLSL is similar to `if(g_MeshTexture == NULL)` in C++?

Comment: The HLSL equivalent is black pixels. No, really... there's no such thing.

Comment: Then should I use flag in c++ code to check whether it has texture or not?

Comment: That would be better, yes. This would actually work.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing built-in for HLSL to test this.

You can add an extra client-loaded parameter to tell the shader if the texture is valid or not, or create a second alternative shader that executes without that texture read in cases where the texture isn't deined (and assigned by the client C++ prog)